# under which conditions can the error escape try-catch with Exception class?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

Which error conditions will not be caught by this try-catch block?

```
    try
    {
       //some codes
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       //log error
    }
```

Background:
I implemented a server which runs external executables (with `ProcessBuilder`). So basically, I don't want the errors in the try block to kill the server. Catching `Throwable` might be the better option here, but I would like to know what else can escape `Exception` or more robust alternatives if any. Thanks!

Comment: see http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129

Answer (score 1):

Anything that's not an `Exception`.

Take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html for Javas own Exceptions (you can create your own by extending the `Exception` class).

Take note also that there is a difference between `Error` and `Exception`.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html

Also, how do you plan on recovering from *all* Exceptions that exists?
If an Exception is thrown, you have reached a state where something is terribly wrong. Not knowing **what** that wrong is, it can be very hard to actually recover, leaving your server in a non-functional state. So while your server doesn't die in the sense that you see an Exception (and by that can trace back what went wrong), you will most likely be in a non-functional state anyhow.

If you haven't already done so, take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/ for dealing with exceptions. Or read it for an refresher.